# How to insert default contraint's value as a column value at the time of Table creation?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, create-table, default-constraint

I am running ORACLE. And I am stuck with a problem. Can anyone tell me, how can I set a **DEFAULT** constraint's value as a column value from that same table during creation ? For example:

```
CREATE table testing
(
 id varchar2(20),
 name varchar2(20),
 myvalue varchar2(30) default id + name
)
```

In the above table, how can I set the **myvalue**'s default constraint's value as the concatenated value of **id** and **name** ?? That is, I want the **myvalue** field's value to be the values of id and name fields **when the table is being created** OR **using the CREATE table command ONLY**. How can it be done?

Please help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: Be aware, concatenation of two `varchar2(20)` values may result in VARCHAR(**40**). `varchar2(30)` is not sufficient in this case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I overlooked it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to modify your table as:

```
ALTER TABLE testing
MODIFY (myvalue VARCHAR2(40) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (id || ' ' || name) VIRTUAL);
```

or you can try to create a TRIGGER like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER     myTrigger
BEFORE     INSERT OR UPDATE
ON     testing
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     :NEW.myvalue:= :NEW.id
                || ' '
                || :NEW.name;
END;
```

Comment: You don't need `TO_CHAR(...)` for a VARCHAR2 data type.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but the extra space added in the trigger suggests to declare `myvalue` as `varchar2(41)`.

Comment: **Sorry everyone.. Perhaps I couldnot define my question well. Actually I want to set the default constraint's value at the time of Table creation only. How is that possible ? I have edited my question.**

Comment: @LightInfinite: You can't. To quote the documentation: "A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to... other columns". The solutions provided by this answer are the best alternatives.